# Reg Performance : Data Transformation using Stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried transforming only 3M records in snowflake using XL warehouse.The transformation rules are attached.
The error records are written into an error table and success records are written into the clean table.
The warehouse used is XL and the time taken for processing is 1hr5mins.
It seems the time taken is quite high as compared to the number of records and the transformation rules.
Could anyone please take a look into the stored procedure and suggest if the code has to be modified to improve performance.
Thanks

```
create or replace procedure clean_transform_table(UPLOAD_DATE_IN VARCHAR)
returns varchar not null
  language javascript
  as
$$

//-------------define function to check valid date format
function isValidDate(datevalue) {
    var pattern = /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/;
    return datevalue.match(pattern);
}

//--------define function to check valid email
function isvalidEmail(email) {
    var pattern = /\S+@\S+\.com$/;
    return email.match(pattern);
}

//------------define function to insert error records
function insertErrorRecords(errorDetails){
if (errorDetails.length > 0){
        var errorDetails = errorDetails.toString();
        var cmd = "insert into error_records_log values"+errorDetails;
        var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
            {
                sqlText: cmd
            }
        );
        stmt.execute();
}

}

//-------function to check valid birth date
function birthDateCheck(row_num, person_id, birth_date,recordStatus) {

    if (birth_date == null || birth_date.trim() == '' || isValidDate(birth_date.trim().toString()) == null) {
        var arr = [row_num,person_id,tableName,birthDateVar,"Value is null or empty or invalid",update_date,birth_date];  
        var arr = "'" + arr.join("','") + "'";
        errorDetails.push( "("+arr+")" );
        return 1;

    } else {
        return recordStatus;
    }

}


//------function to check valid gender value
function genderCheck(row_num, person_id, gender,recordStatus) {

    if (gender == null || !['M', 'F'].includes(gender.trim())) {
        var arr = [row_num,person_id,tableName,genderVar,"Value is null or other in [M,F]",update_date,gender];  
        var arr = "'" + arr.join("','") + "'";
        errorDetails.push( "("+arr+")" );
       return 1;
    } else {
        return recordStatus;
    }

}

//--------function to check valid country value
function countryCheck(row_num, person_id, country,country_of_Birth,recordStatus) {

    if (country != country_of_Birth) {
       var arr = [row_num,person_id,tableName,countryVar,"Value is not same as country_of_Birth",update_date,country];  
       var arr = "'" + arr.join("','") + "'";
       errorDetails.push( "("+arr+")" );
       return 1;
    } else {
        return recordStatus;
    }

}

//-------function to check valid loan amount
function loanCheck(row_num, person_id, loan_amount,recordStatus) {

    if (loan_amount != null && loan_amount.trim() != '' && loan_amount.trim() < 0) {
       var arr = [row_num,person_id,tableName,loanVar,"Value is negative number",update_date,loan_amount];  
       var arr = "'" + arr.join("','") + "'";
       errorDetails.push( "("+arr+")" );
       return 1;
    } else {
        return recordStatus;
    }

}

//------function to validate email
function emailCheck(row_num, person_id, email,recordStatus) {
    if (email != null && isvalidEmail(email) == null){

       var arr = [row_num,person_id,tableName,emailVar,"value is invalid email",update_date,email];  
       var arr = "'" + arr.join("','") + "'";
       errorDetails.push( "("+arr+")" );
       return 1;
    } else {
        return recordStatus;
    }

}

//----------function extract all data, validate and trace errors
function validateAllDataTraceErrors(){
var cmd = "select * from SF_STRUCT_STAGE_RAW where upload_date = to_date(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD')";
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
    {
        sqlText: cmd
        ,binds:[UPLOAD_DATE_IN]
    }
);
var resultSet = stmt.execute();

//----loop thru all the data
while (resultSet.next()) {

    var recordStatus = 0;
    var row_num = resultSet.getColumnValueAsString('ROW_NUM');
    var person_id = resultSet.getColumnValueAsString('PERSON_ID');
    var birth_date = resultSet.getColumnValueAsString('BIRTH_DATE');
    var gender = resultSet.getColumnValueAsString('GENDER');
    var country = resultSet.getColumnValueAsString('COUNTRY');
    var country_of_Birth = resultSet.getColumnValueAsString('COUNTRY_OF_BIRTH');
    var loan_amount = resultSet.getColumnValueAsString('LOAN_AMOUNT');
    var email = resultSet.getColumnValueAsString('EMAIL');

    //----birth date check
    var recordStatus = birthDateCheck(row_num, person_id, birth_date,errorDetails,recordStatus);

    //------gender check
    var recordStatus = genderCheck(row_num, person_id, gender,recordStatus);

    //------country and country of birth check
    var recordStatus = countryCheck(row_num, person_id, country,country_of_Birth,recordStatus);

    //------email check
    var recordStatus = emailCheck(row_num, person_id, email,recordStatus);

    //------Loan amount negative check
    var recordStatus = loanCheck(row_num, person_id, loan_amount,recordStatus);

    //------Update error Rownum's in variable
    if (recordStatus == 1) {
        errorRowNum.push(row_num)
    }
}

}

//------function to transfer valid records to clean table
function transfer_valid_records(errorRowNum) {
var condition = "";

if (errorRowNum.length > 0){
condition = "where upload_date = to_date(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD') and raw.row_num not in ("+ errorRowNum.toString()+");";
}else{
condition = "where upload_date = to_date(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD');";
}

if (errorRowNum.length == 0){
errorRowNum = '';
}
var cmd = `insert into SF_STRUCT_CLEAN
select 
seq1.nextval,
raw.Person_id,  
reverse(raw.Given_Name),
reverse(raw.Family_Name),
raw.Title,
raw.BIRTH_DATE,
lkp_gen.description,
raw.Mobile_Phone,
raw.Email,
raw.Address_Line_1,
raw.Postcode,
raw.State,
raw.Country,
raw.Country_of_Birth,
raw.loan_amount,
current_date()
from SF_STRUCT_STAGE_RAW raw
left join lkp_gender lkp_gen
on raw.Gender = lkp_gen.code `+condition;

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
        {
            sqlText: cmd,
            binds:[UPLOAD_DATE_IN]
        }
    );
    stmt.execute();
}

//----------------------call main functions 
try{

//-------------define variables
var birthDateVar = 'BIRTH_DATE';
var genderVar = 'GENDER';
var countryVar = 'COUNTRY';
var loanVar = 'LOAN_AMOUNT';
var emailVar = 'EMAIL';
var tableName = 'SF_STRUCT_STAGE_RAW';
var errorRowNum = [];
var errorDetails = [];
var currentDate =  new Date();
var update_date = currentDate.getFullYear()+'-'+(currentDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+currentDate.getDate();

validateAllDataTraceErrors();

insertErrorRecords(errorDetails);

transfer_valid_records(errorRowNum);

result = 'Success';
}
catch (err){
result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt; 
}

return result;
$$
  ;
```

The raw table has following schema
Columns Data Type
ROW_NUM NUMBER(38,0)
PERSON_ID   NUMBER(38,0)
GIVEN_NAME  VARCHAR(100)
FAMILY_NAME VARCHAR(100)
TITLE   VARCHAR(100)
BIRTH_DATE  VARCHAR(100)
GENDER  VARCHAR(100)
MOBILE_PHONE    VARCHAR(100)
EMAIL   VARCHAR(100)
ADDRESS_LINE_1  VARCHAR(100)
POSTCODE    VARCHAR(100)
STATE   VARCHAR(100)
COUNTRY VARCHAR(100)
COUNTRY_OF_BIRTH    VARCHAR(100)
LOAN_AMOUNT VARCHAR(50)
FILE_NAME   VARCHAR(100)
UPLOAD_DATE DATE

The transformation rules are very basic as below
[image: Mapping and transformation document]

Answer (score 0):

1) You are processing rows one by one. I see that you use regular expressions, so it should be possible to convert this stored procedure to pure SQL (or at least process the rows as a set).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html

2) It holds failed row numbers in JavaScript objects, you may have memory issues in case there are huge number of rows fail.

Comment: Well, its true that this can be done in pure sql but this is just poc wherein the rules are simple however there might be more complex rules that aren't possible in pure sql.So i wanted to apply transformation row by row.I understand that there can be memory issues in the usage of Javascript objects but then i do want to track the errors as per the error table defined. Even with all this the time taken to process is really huge as compared to other ETL tools wherein the process happens row by row.

Comment: Even in this case, instead of opening a cursor and looping for each row, it would be better to run a SELECT command calling your UDFs together. SELECT * FOM Y WHERE checkmail(x) AND morecomplex(z). Of course, there can be situations that it's not possible to use this method, then there would be performance issues.